# Reload CHROME's extension's script?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Everytime I make a change in extension's script (it is loaded as unpacked), i have to reload the extension (from extensions page) and only after that it loads the updated script... This is very annoying when we are on an extensive development of script/file.

is there any solution to reload the file always fresh (as i think, on extension installation it caches  all files of that extension..)

Comment: AFAIK there are several js helpers for hot-reloading extensions. Basically it's chrome.runtime.reload()

Answer (score 1):

google chrome is open some js file when the browser is open (specially background js) and not load/read every time because of performance point of view if you are trying to made changes in background js you need to reload every time for effact your change.

[click here to view reload opction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypfc1.png)

i would suggest when you are changes any script or css please reload chrome ext and hard refresh your page (CTRL+F5) and keep disable casing in chrome DEV mode